Need parent project home with multiple children projects under per stages with documents
We have many projects and smaller projects that spin off each other. What's best way to have our files set up in SharePoint?
Projects
Cloud 1
Cloud 2
Cloud 3
App Mod 1
App mod 2
Cyber 1
Cyber 2
Cyber 3

Then we need their files stored under their projects & usually it's by 5 stage gates. What's best way to set this up?

It depends. If you need seperate permissions for each project. We create a sitecollection for each project and use different document libraries for smaller sub projects.
